# Creating Shortcuts in Okular

Tags: 18.04, shortcut-keys, okular

I want to add a shortcut to Okular that activates the highlighting tool. I am aware of the "configure shortcuts" tab but the commands that it contains are limited and I want to know how to add a specific command to the list. It's a weird choice of commands, such as all of the colors of the "drawing tool", so I suppose there is a way to achieve what I have in mind.

(I am also aware that F6 opens the drawing tools side bar, but I don't want to click on the highlighter every time I use it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Kubuntu 18.04 with Okular in "Browse" mode, pressing <kbd>F6</kbd> brings up the Review tools.

Hovering your mouse pointer over items in the Review toolbar will provide a tooltip describing the function with a number as the image shows for the highlighter.

[image: Tooltip with corresponding number]

While browsing a pdf file, the mouse pointer is normally in the shape of an open hand. But, if you wish to annotate something using the Review tools, pressing <kbd>4</kbd>, for example, will

- cause the pointer to change to an insertion bar and
- activate the highlighting function

By pressing your left mouse button and dragging the insertion bar over text, you can highlight that text.

Upon releasing the left mouse button, the pointer changes back to a hand.

Move somewhere else in your document. Press <kbd>4</kbd> again. Once more, the pointer changes again to an insertion bar allowing you to highlight additional text and so on.

You can press any number corresponding to the review feature you want to use.

The annotation bar will remain visible until you press F6 again.

Comment: You can also double-click on an annotation tool to make it stick until you click it again or right click anywhere in the document.

Answer (score 1):

The annotation palette must be open to use annotation tools. As @DK Bose already mentioned, there are already keyboard shortcuts assigned to the preinstalled annotation tools (hover over a tool to display its shortcut).

The shortcuts are defined in `~/.config/okularpartrc`. It is a bit hard to read because all tools are defined in one line, but the shortcuts are defined inside `<shortcut>` tags. Instead of single keys, you can also define combinations using modifiers, e.g.:

```
<shortcut>ctrl+shift+j</shortcut>
```

**Edit:**
Apparently, shortcut assignment is hard coded in the annotation configuration (see [here](https://github.com/KDE/okular/blob/master/conf/widgetannottools.cpp)). This means that as soon as you open Okular's configuration and click Apply or Ok, changes in `okularpartrc` will be overriden. The first nine tools will automatically be assigned the numbers 1-9 as shortcuts.

Answer (score 1):

In later versions of Okular, like 21.12, that shortcut was added to the list:

[image]

There are other major changes in these new versions. The annotations appear as a separate customizable set of toolbar icons:

[image]

and, when activated (F6), they are integrated with the main toolbar:

[image]